# React Native App Stuck On Jetify in dev mode

Tags: react-native, android-jetifier

I'm trying to migrate my app on 0.60, but it keeps getting stuck on jetify process.

Basically, after this line:

> info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.

It's just stuck and does nothing. And I need jetifier for react-native-firebase and some other native libraries. Any suggestions?

**Update**

It seems the problem is in symlinks. I'm using Lerna.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end what I did was rewriting a jetify specifying which modules I need to jetify.

My jetify index.js:

```
const {fork} = require('child_process');
const {join} = require('path');
const {getClassesMapping, readDir, chunk} = require('./src/utils');

const cpus = require('os').cpus().length;

const arg = process.argv.slice(2)[0];
const mode = arg && (arg === 'reverse' || arg === '-r') ? 'reverse' : 'forward';
const SEARCH_DIRS = [
  ........modules here
];

const classesMapping = getClassesMapping();
for (const SEARCH_DIR of SEARCH_DIRS) {
  const files = readDir(SEARCH_DIR);

  console.log(
    `Jetifier found ${
      files.length
    } file(s) to ${mode}-jetify. Using ${cpus} workers...`,
  );

  for (const filesChunk of chunk(files, cpus)) {
    const worker = fork(join(__dirname, 'src', 'worker.js'));
    worker.send({filesChunk, classesMapping, mode});
  }
}
```

And `postinstall` in package.json:

```
"postinstall": "cp ./jetify.js ./node_modules/jetifier/index.js"
```

Answer (score 4):

There is also one more situation when the `npx react-native run-android` stucks at *jetifying state*

If you run `npm run android` it'll start the *metro server* as well,

However, to re-run `npm run android`, **you need to close the metro command window** and allow `npm run android` to start a new metro server

Comment: This was the solution for me. I had some old merto command window openned :)